# Magento Custom Shipping Module multiple rates not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

**Edit**

It looks like the called to get the rate code is returning the same thing for all of those shipping options.  It looks like I need to find a way to define the reate code for each shipping option.

**End Edit**

I created a custom shipping module in Magento for UPS Freight shipping.  I needed options for Freight + Lift Gate, Freight + Residential, and Freight + Lift Gate & Residential.  Per a response on another board, instead of having a checkbox for each of these options I just create separate methods.

[image: shipping options]

As you can see from the image, Magento is calculating the prices correctly.  The issue I have is that when I select one of the options and hit "update total", it reverts back to the first option with the lowest price.  After inspecting the inputs on the radio buttons, I found that they all have the same value.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <input name="estimate_method[2]" type="radio" value="excellence_excellence" id="s_method_excellence_excellence_2" class="radio">
    <label for="s_method_excellence_excellence_2">Freight<span class="price">$678.88</span></label>
</li>
<li>
    <input name="estimate_method[2]" type="radio" value="excellence_excellence" id="s_method_excellence_excellence_2" class="radio">
    <label for="s_method_excellence_excellence_2">Freight (Residential)<span class="price">$744.66</span></label>
</li>
.
. and so on.
.
</ul>
```

Since all of the inputs have the same value "excellence_excellence", it makes sense that the price would just default back to the first one.  Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix this.

Below are links to my Model class, config.xml, and system.xml files.  Any help, thoughts, or resources provided would be greatly appreciated.

[Model](http://pastebin.com/kgvpScHF)
[Config](http://pastebin.com/afH1Usjf)
[System](http://pastebin.com/b6HVyUKx)

Comment: A HTML element's ID must be unique in the whole document, your code breaks that.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan I'm aware of that.  This code is generated automatically somewhere in Magento.  My question is where can I override or fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your model file, and it has this:

```
$method->setCarrier($this->_code);
$method->setMethod($this->_code);
```

and $this->_code is "excellence"   so you might consider change method by adding name of the allowed method like :

```
$method->setMethod($this->_code.$allowedmethod_code); //where allowedmethod_code have to be set based on your custom method names
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"<input name="estimate_method[]"
```

This will generate a unique array index for this specific input.

Comment: What file in Magento do modify to make this change?  Like I said in my response above, the code is generated automatically and I don't know where that happens at.